# What specific UIView objects must use autolayout to have the app scale properly on the iPhone 6/6+?

Tags: ios

Must all UIView objects use autolayout? Does Apple have official documentation about this?

The reason I ask is because I am working on an app and most of the UIViews (UIViewControllers, and most large views) are placed using autolayout, however something is obviously not scaling properly since the status bar is massive on the 6+. A particular pageViewController is laid out using the UIScreen frame size however does that cause the entire app to lose scaling ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use auto layout at all.

It's up to you what views you will use it on, if any.

Auto Layout is often the easiest choice but all the other options work just as well on the iPhone 6/6+ as they did on all previous iOS devices.

If the status bar is big, then iOS 8 is assuming that your app has never been tested on the newer phones. This is probably because you don't have a launch image of the correct size.

To fix it, create launch images for the 6 and 6+ as documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

Note that iOS 8 has support for using an Xib file instead of a launch images. This is a better approach but it has a few bugs and is not compatible with iOS 7.

Comment: This is very good to know, thank you for writing this up. I wish Apple made some of this documentation more apparent.

Comment: @user3721428 the documentation is there, all this has been covered by Apple in detail, it's just a lot of work to read all of it. Stack Overflow is here when you don't have time to do that. ;-)